# ASP.NET MVC incorect generation url when using pagination

Tags: asp.net, razor, routes

I have to acion

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{forumName}", Order = 8)]
    [Route("{forumName}/Page/{page}", Order = 7)]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "forumName;page", Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowForum(string forumName, int page = 1)
```

**and**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [RefreshDetectFilter]
    [Block(VisibleBlock = false)]
    [Route("~/Forums/{forum}/{topicName}", Order = 6)]
    [Route("~/Forums/{forum}/{topicName}/Page/{page}", Order = 5)]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "topicName;page", Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowTopic(string forum, string topicName, int page = 1)
```

**Razor**

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("ShowForum", "Forums", new {forumName = Model.NameTranslit})" title="@Model.Name">@Model.Name</a>
```

**and**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ShowTopic", "Forums", new { forum = Model.CurrentForumTranslite, topicName = Model.TitleTranslite })" title="@Model.Title">@Model.Title</a>
```

When I at page with example this

*/Forums/Test/Page/2*

Link to the sub forum I have normal link, but link to the topic I have with page

*/Forums/Test/Test_Topic/Page/2*

But should be

*/Forums/Test/Test_Topic*

How I understand. I have this bug because in my actions I have the same route parameter for page

What I should to do to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how the workaround the problem

For route ShowTopic

```
[Route("~/Forums/{forum}/{topicName}", Order = 6)]
```

I added name

```
[Route("{forum}/{topicName}", Name = "showTopic", Order = 6)]
```

And for get url at topic, I'm using Url.RouteUrl

```
 <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("showTopic", new { forum = Model.CurrentForumTranslite, topicName = Model.TitleTranslite })" title="@Model.Title">@Model.Title</a>
```