# MvcSiteMapProvider bug with pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, mvcsitemapprovider

It's continue [ASP.NET MVC incorect generation url when using pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150709/asp-net-mvc-incorect-generation-url-when-using-pagination), but there I found how fix it. How fix that when using @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() I can't understand.

Problem in that when in actions ShowForum or ShowTopic and when I using pagination some forum or topic. In @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() I get url at parent page with number of page

**UPDATE**

For route configuration I'm using route attribute

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{forumName}", Name = "showForum", Order = 6)]
    [Route("{forumName}/Page/{page}", Order = 5)]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "forumName;page", Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowForum(string forumName, int page = 1)

    [HttpGet]
    [RefreshDetectFilter]
    [Block(VisibleBlock = false)]
    [Route("{forum}/{topicName}", Name = "showTopic", Order = 8)]
    [Route("{forum}/{topicName}/Page/{page}", Order = 7)]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "topicName;page", Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowTopic(string forum, string topicName, int page = 1)
```

My ForumDynamicNodeProvider

```
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        var rootTitle = ManagerLocalization.Get("Forums", "FORUMS");
        var pageParameter = new List<string> { "page" };
        var url = "~/Forums";
        var attr = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Controller", "Forums" } };

        var nodes = new List<DynamicNode>
                        {
                            new DynamicNode
                                {
                                    Key = "forum_home",
                                    Title = rootTitle,
                                    Url = url,
                                    Attributes = attr
                                }
                        };

        var forums = this._forumsService.GetAllForumsForMap();
        var topics = this._forumsService.GetAllTopicsForMap();

        foreach (var forum in forums)
        {
            var forumRouteValue = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "forumName", forum.NameTranslit } };

            nodes.Add(new DynamicNode
            {
                ParentKey = forum.ForumId != -1 ? $"forum_{forum.ForumId}" : "forum_home",

                Key = $"forum_{forum.Id}",
                Title = forum.Name,
                PreservedRouteParameters = pageParameter,
                Controller = "Forums",
                Action = "ShowForum",
                RouteValues = forumRouteValue,

            });

            var forumTopics = topics.Where(item => item.ForumId == forum.Id);

            foreach (var topic in forumTopics)
            {
                var topicRouteValue = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "forum", forum.NameTranslit }, { "topicName", topic.TitleTranslite } };

                nodes.Add(new DynamicNode
                {
                    ParentKey = $"forum_{forum.Id}",
                    Key = $"topic_{topic.Id}",
                    Title = topic.Title,
                    PreservedRouteParameters = pageParameter,
                    Controller = "Forums",
                    Action = "ShowTopic",
                    RouteValues = topicRouteValue,
                });
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your node configuration. You should also post your route configuration here (rather than linking to another question) as it pertains to paging. It is unclear what the "solution" was on your other question - it appears you just took the pagination off of the route.

Comment: Ok. I added route configuration and ForumDynamicNodeProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how this fix, thank you to **NightOwl888**. I'm not the first time understood what should to do.

First I removed initialization **PreservedRouteParameters** in **ForumDynamicNodeProvider**

Second I added in action

```
        if (forumPage > 1)
        {
            var node = SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(forumName);

            if (node != null)
            {
                node.RouteValues["forumPage"] = forumPage;
            }
        }
```

Also I need change generation tree in ForumDynamicNodeProvider because SiteMaps.Current doesn't work in async

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same route key name `{page}` in two different places in the same node ancestry in combination with `PreservedRouteParameters`. `PreservedRouteParameters` gets its data from the *current* request. So, it is important that a route key have the same meaning in each request in the same node ancestry. For it to work correctly with `PreservedRouteParamters`, you need to do three things:

1. Use a different route key for each separate page parameter (for example, `{forumPage}` and `{page}`).
2. Ensure the ancestor page parameter is passed to the request of its descendants, so when building the URL to an ancestor node the value is in the current request. The simplest way is to build the URL with the page information of all ancestors (`{forumName}/Page/{forumPage}/{topicName}/Page/{page}`).
3. Any route keys that have the same meaning between nodes should stay the same (`{forumName}` in both routes).

Then you need to add the parameters when building the URL of the child node. You **must** build the URL manually within your application because the request will not have all of the parameters unless you do.

```
@Html.ActionLink("TheTopicName", "ShowTopic", "Forums", 
    new { forumName = 1, forumPage = 2, topicName = "foo", page = 1 }, null)
```

> The reason you **must** supply all of the data in the child node request is because the ancestor node needs it to build its URL. It pulls this information from the request, so it must be present in the request for it to function. `MvcSiteMapProvider` has no way of knowing what the current page number of the ancestor node is unless it is provided in the request by a URL that is built *outside* of your menu.

See the `MvcSiteMapProvider-Forcing-A-Match-2-Levels` project in the code download for [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position#forcing-a-match) for a similar configuration and the solution. In that case, it is using `productId` instead of `forumPage` as the parameter that is preserved on the descendant nodes so you can navigate back to the parent product.

> Note that you *could* use a similar configuration (with `PreservedRouteParameters` and `SiteMapTitleAttribute`) for your entire forum rather than using a dynamic node provider. However, in that case I would suggest you [disable the `/sitemap.xml` endpoint](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider#mvcsitemapprovider_enablesitemapsxml) and [roll your own](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

Comment: If correctly to say. Change keys of routes. That help with topic, but for sub forum it's didn't help me

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am not sure how I can be any more clear than this, as I have already provided a working sample - when using `PreservedRouteParameters` the all of the data needs to be in the request of the child node or the ancestor URL won't be built.

Comment: How I wrote, I fix problem with link to topic, I have problem with @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() in forum when I'm using pagination